# Ruby installed but not running

Tags: ruby, rvm

I installed Ruby with RVM succesfully, and I installed NodeJS as well.

`$ rvm install ruby` shows that ruby 2.1.3 is already installed.

When trying to run Ruby at the prompt I am told:

```
The program 'ruby' can be found in the following packages:
 * ruby
 * ruby1.8
```

What is the problem?

Comment: in terminal 'ruby -v' ?

Comment: Yes,$ ruby -v . The answer is:   The program 'ruby' can be found in the following packages:
 * ruby
 * ruby1.8
Try: sudo apt-get install <selected package>

Comment: You've probably failed to complete your RVM installation. Until you source `rvm.sh` nothing will work as you expect.

Comment: But it seems rvm runs properly.$ rvm -v  .rvm 1.25.33 (stable) by Wayne E. Seguin <wayneeseguin@gmail.com>, Michal Papis <mpapis@gmail.com> [https://rvm.io/]

Comment: Don't use `sudo apt-get install`. That completely circumvents the use of RVM and will cause worse confusion. Carefully read the [RVM installation page](http://rvm.io/rvm/install), including its debugging tips.

Comment: try `rvm --default use 2.1.3` and then do `ruby -v`